# How to find app permissions in the new Google Play Store web version?

Tags: google-play-store, permissions

In the new updates, the Google Play Store web does not show the permissions of apps.

If I want to check the permission of an app before downloading it, how can I do it now?

In the picture, missing permissions section in Google Play:

> [image]

Comment: Please specify yout device model number and play store version. The option 'does' show up on my phone (rmx2193 with play store version 30.6.16-21)

Comment: @karthiknair looks like this is about [the new web version of the Play Store](https://9to5google.com/2022/05/26/google-play-web-redesign/).

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh wow so they're finally redesigning it after an eterenity and removing vital things (ah Google it it is)