# Getting permissions for new apps and apps updates on Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, permissions

That's already been discussed on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31447716), however the question remains:

- How can you learn the permissions required by a new app *without* installing it?
- How can you learn the new permissions required by an app update again *without* installing it?

Google has hidden app permissions both from the Google Play app and the Google Play website in the middle of May 2022 and replaced it with pretty inane "[Data Safety](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00fxg.png)". No one has paid attention, I've even approached at least three news outlets including Android Police, 9to5 Google, and Ars Technica - no one cared. It's a crazy serious issue and I'm appalled I'm the only person among **two billion** Android users who've noticed the abrupt change.

If [an] APK [file] is available on the Internet it is a solved issue, however it's often not the case, especially for paid apps.

Comment: Possible dupe: [How to find app permissions in the new Google Play Store web version?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246899/44325) (no proper answers yet. [karthik's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246899/how-to-find-app-permissions-in-the-new-google-play-store-web-version#comment330888_246899) mentioned that the permissions are still visible from the Play Store app and I personally have confirmed it, while [Firelord's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord) is a potential alternative workaround)

Comment: Nothing is visible in my app - it mirrors what's seen on the play website.

AppBrain: https://www.appbrain.com/app/diablo-immortal/com.blizzard.diablo.immortal -> No permissions found. Various APK explorers? I've said exactly why it can't work for me.

Comment: Re: Play Store app, could you double-check by tapping the "About this app/game" header and then scroll down to the bottom for "App permissions"? I couldn't check for Diablo Immortal because it's not released yet in my country, but permissions are still shown for other games/apps from there. Otherwise, perhaps my Play Store app hasn't been updated? (currently v30.6.16-21 [O] [PR] 448548437)

Comment: Oh, God, `org.mozilla.fenix` (Firefox Browser (Nightly for Developers)) -> More Info: Everyone Unrestricted Internet. That's bloody it. Now, once installed -> App Info -> Permissions -> Triple dots at the top -> All Permissions -> a shitton of permissions. Do you actually use Android or use an emulator with some old Play Store app?

Comment: Now I'm curious, I'm using a real Pixel 3a on Android 12 and Nexus 5 on Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1). Could you post the Play Store version and screenshots of what is shown on your Play Store app? Because this is what is shown on my current Play Store app: ["App permissions" below "More Info"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDJKFl.png), [the permissions without installing the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30gphl.png)

Comment: In the Google Play app version 30.6.16-21 [0] [PR] 448548437 - nothing is visible. https://i.imgur.com/7GRZZcg.png No idea what app version you're using. This is not what I see, it's now completely replaced with useless Data Safety.

Comment: ArtemS.Tashkinov A friend of mine has Play Store with same build as @AndrewT. has and he was able to see "App Permissions" too. Perhaps this is region related build variation. It is possible a new build update would remove this category for us too.

Comment: My Google Play store is set to the US, I've tried using it while connecting to VPNs from other countries - the result is the same.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, I encourage you to post the AppBrain site you mentioned as an answer to this question—it’s a way to readily see an app’s permissions without needing to install a special app just to see permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that Google has not killed or restricted off-the-record APIs which allowed Play Store to get app permissions info back in the day. This API *might be* what Raccoon and Aurora Store are able to access to still successfully show app permissions for apps without installing them.

#### [Aurora Store](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.aurora.store/)

Install it from F-Droid, setup a pseudo account, search your app, scroll down on the app page, tap *Permission* (worked on v4.1.1).

See example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys1jj.jpg).

#### [Raccoon APK Downloader](https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/apk-downloader/)

Raccoon is a desktop-only Java app. You need Java runtime installed to run this app. See its [user guide](https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/apk-downloader-v4/about-raccoon/) for your OS specific setup.

Once it is setup, search your app, click on the app entry, and in the bottom left click on *Permission* to see Permissions (worked on v4.20.0).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Since July 21, 2022, Google has added back permission details on the Play Store.**

In [a tweet](https://twitter.com/AndroidDev/status/1550134137104740352) by the official Android Developers account (@AndroidDev),

> Privacy and transparency are core values in the Android community. We heard your feedback that you find the app permissions section in Google Play useful, and we've decided to reinstate it. The app permissions section will be back shortly.

As of September 2022, this has been added back to both web and app versions on the original location:

- Web: About this app - Permissions - View details
- App: About this app - App permissions - See More